# What is the difference between ? and Object in Java generics?

Tags: java, generics

I'm using Eclipse to help me clean up some code to use Java generics properly.  Most of the time it's doing an excellent job of inferring types, but there are some cases where the inferred type has to be as generic as possible: Object.  But Eclipse seems to be giving me an option to choose between a type of Object and a type of '?'.

So what's the difference between:

```
HashMap<String, ?> hash1;
```

and

```
HashMap<String, Object> hash2;
```

Comment: See the official tutorial on [Wildcards](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html). It explains it well and gives an example of why it's necessary over simply using Object.

Comment: @BenS the link you have posted refers to the wrong place of the oracle documentation. The difference between Type<Object> and Type<?> is start being explained on the [previous page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/subtype.html)

Answer (score 173, accepted):

An instance of `HashMap<String, String>` matches `Map<String, ?>` but not `Map<String, Object>`. Say you want to write a method that accepts maps from `String`s to anything: If you would write

```
public void foobar(Map<String, Object> ms) {
    ...
}
```

you can't supply a `HashMap<String, String>`. If you write

```
public void foobar(Map<String, ?> ms) {
    ...
}
```

it works!

A thing sometimes misunderstood in Java's generics is that `List<String>` is not a subtype of `List<Object>`. (But `String[]` is in fact a subtype of `Object[]`, that's one of the reasons why generics and arrays don't mix well. (arrays in Java are covariant, generics are not, they are *invariant*)).

Sample:
If you'd like to write a method that accepts `List`s of `InputStream`s and subtypes of `InputStream`, you'd write

```
public void foobar(List<? extends InputStream> ms) {
    ...
}
```

By the way: [Joshua Bloch's Effective Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201310058) is an excellent resource when you'd like to understand the not so simple things in Java. (Your question above is also covered very well in the book.)

Comment: is this right way to go to use  ResponseEntity<?> on controller level for all my controller functions?

Comment: Object is the supertype of all Java classes, however, a collection of Object is not the supertype of any collection. For example, a List<Object> is not the supertype of List<String> and assigning a variable of type List<Object> to a variable of type List<String> will cause a compiler error.

Answer (score 48):

Another way to think about this problem is that

```
HashMap<String, ?> hash1;
```

is equivalent to

```
HashMap<String, ? extends Object> hash1;
```

Couple this knowledge with the "Get and Put Principle" in section (2.4) from *[Java Generics and Collections](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596527754/)*:

> The Get and Put Principle: use an
>   extends wildcard when you only get
>   values out of a structure, use super
>   wildcard when you only put values into
>   a structure, and don't use a wildcard
>   when you both get and put.

and the wild card may start making more sense, hopefully.

Comment: If "?" confuses you, "? extends Object" will likely confuse you more. Maybe.

Comment: Trying to provide "thinking tools" to allow one to reason about this difficult subject. Provided additional info on extending wildcards.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info.  I'm still digesting it. :)

Comment: `HashMap<String, ? extends Object> ` so it only prevents `null` to be added in the hashmap?

Answer (score 14):

It's easy to understand if you remember that `Collection<Object>` is just a generic collection that contains objects of type `Object`, but `Collection<?>` is a super type of all types of collections.

Answer (score 5):

The answers above covariance cover most cases but miss one thing:

"?" is inclusive of "Object" in the class hierarchy.  You could say that String is a type of Object and Object is a type of ?.  Not everything matches Object, but everything matches ?.

```
int test1(List<?> l) {
  return l.size();
}

int test2(List<Object> l) {
  return l.size();
}

List<?> l1 = Lists.newArrayList();
List<Object> l2 = Lists.newArrayList();
test1(l1);  // compiles because any list will work
test1(l2);  // compiles because any list will work
test2(l1);  // fails because a ? might not be an Object
test2(l2);  // compiled because Object matches Object
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't safely put anything into `Map<String, ?>`, because you don't know what type the values are supposed to be.

You can put any object into a `Map<String, Object>`, because the value is known to be an `Object`.

Comment: "You can't safely put anything into Map<String, ?>" False. You CAN, that's its purpose.

Comment: Wrong, Ben. Doing this will produce "unchecked" warnings. The purpose of wildcards is to write code that can operate on any generic type.

Comment: Ben is wrong, the only value you can put into a collection of type <?> is null, whereas you can put anything into a collection of type <Object>.

Comment: From the link I gave in my answer: "Since we don't know what the element type of c stands for, we cannot add objects to it.". I apologize for the misinformation.

Comment: the biggest problem is I don't understand how it's possible that you can't add anything into HashMap<String,?>, if we consider that EVERYTHING except primitives are objects. Or is it for primitives?

Comment: @avalon Elsewhere, there is a reference to that map that is bounded. For example, it might be a `Map<String,Integer>`. Only `Integer` objects should put stored in the map as values. But since you don't know the type of the value (it's `?`), you don't know if if it's safe to call `put(key, "x")`, `put(key, 0)`, or anything else.

Answer (score 4):

Declaring `hash1` as a `HashMap<String, ?>` dictates that the variable `hash1` can hold any `HashMap` that has a key of `String` and any type of value.

```
HashMap<String, ?> map;
map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
map = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

All of the above is valid, because the **variable** `map` can store any of those hash maps. That variable doesn't care what the Value type is, of the hashmap it holds.

Having a wildcard does **not**, however, let you put any type of object into your map. as a matter of fact, with the hash map above, you can't put anything into it using the `map` variable:

```
map.put("A", new Integer(0));
map.put("B", new Object());
map.put("C", "Some String");
```

All of the above method calls will result in a compile-time error because Java doesn't know what the Value type of the HashMap inside `map` is.

You can still get a value out of the hash map. Although you "don't know the value's type," (because you don't know what type of hash map is inside your variable), you can say that everything is a subclass of `Object` and, so, whatever you get out of the map will be of the type Object:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> myMap = new HashMap<>();// This variable is used to put things into the map.

myMap.put("ABC", 10);

HashMap<String, ?> map = myMap;
Object output = map.get("ABC");// Valid code; Object is the superclass of everything, (including whatever is stored our hash map).

System.out.println(output);
```

The above block of code will print 10 to the console.

---

So, to finish off, use a `HashMap` with wildcards when you do not care (i.e., it does not matter) what the types of the `HashMap` are, for example:

```
public static void printHashMapSize(Map<?, ?> anyMap) {
    // This code doesn't care what type of HashMap is inside anyMap.
    System.out.println(anyMap.size());
}
```

Otherwise, specify the types that you need:

```
public void printAThroughZ(Map<Character, ?> anyCharacterMap) {
    for (int i = 'A'; i <= 'Z'; i++)
        System.out.println(anyCharacterMap.get((char) i));
}
```

In the above method, we'd need to know that the Map's key is a `Character`, otherwise, we wouldn't know what type to use to get values from it. All objects have a `toString()` method, however, so the map can have any type of object for its values. We can still print the values.