# Java generics, objects and wildcards differences & clarifications

Tags: java, object, generics, wildcard, type-erasure

I wish to understand this concept:

1. `T` object - generic, will be erased into actual type.
2. `?` object - will be erased into what?
3. `Object` object;

What are the differences between `T`, `?` and `Object`?

I can easily understand #1, but what about:

```
Object var;
? var;
```

What is the difference between the two? I have read that I can't use `?` explicitly, like `T` or any other variable, and that `?` is related to objects, not types.
But what is the practical reason? Why can't I just write a `List` of objects (`List<Object>`) instead of a `List` of wildcards (`List<?>`)? As I don't know the types of objects on both cases.
In addition, I would like to know what is the erasure for `?` ?

Comment: I'd start with http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html .  Specifically look up "Wildcard Capture"

Comment: And some more good links in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12043874/java-generics-wildcard-capture-misunderstanding

Comment: http://bayou.io/draft/Capturing_Wildcards.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I will list the main differences between `T` and `?`:

- Basic: `T` is a type parameter and `?` is a wildcard.
- Meaning: `T` is used as a type parameter when defining a generic class. `T` will be replaced by a concrete type when you instantiate the generic class.
  On the other hand, we use `?` when we want to refer to an *unknown* type argument.
- Place of definition: You need to declare `T` on the top of the class, or method if you define a generic method. You can use `?` *everywhere*.
- Mapping: Every use of `T` is mapped to the same type (in the same class). Every use of `?` can be mapped to a different type.
- Object instantiation: You can create objects with the generic parameter `T` like `new ArrayList<T>()`. You cannot instantiate objects but only *pointers* with `?`.
- Collections updating: You can add objects to a collection of type `T`. You cannot add object to a collection of type `?` (since you don't know its type).
- Type erasures: With generics, type erasure applies to the *use* of generics. when generics are used, they are converted into compile-time checks and execution-time casts. So if you have this code for example: `List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();` and then you wish to add to your list so you do `myList.add("Hello World");` and then you want to `get` the item you just added by performing `String myString = myList.get(0);` then the compiler will compile your code to `List myList = new ArrayList();` and `String myString = (String) myList.get(0);` (the `add` stays the same for obvious reasons).
  So basically, at execution time there is *no way* of finding out that `T` is essentially `String` for the list object (that information is gone). 
   
  Now for wildcards the story is different. A wildcard (`?`) is replaced by an `Object` (since it's *unbounded*). This is not very useful. At build-time the compiler will check you are *only* calling `Object`'s behaviours. If you have something like `? extends Foo`, then the `?` is replaced with its bound `Foo` (at build-time the compiler will check you are only passing `Foo` or any of its subtypes (types that inherit from `Foo`) as an argument).

For differences between `?` and `Object` & `T` and `Object` you may read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/678822/what-is-the-difference-between-and-object-in-java-generics) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5207115/java-generics-t-vs-object) respectively.

Comment: It would be good to mention type erasure in here, as the OP mentions it