# Need help understanding the difference between <T> and <?> in Java

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

What is the difference between `List<T>` and `List<?>` ?

I found this type of code when I was going through java doc but couldn't understand the difference.

Comment: I have actually answered this exact question extensively here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34993626/java-generics-objects-and-wildcards-differences-clarifications/34993866#34993866 making this a duplicate

Comment: Nice link @Idos I never knew that, good question too bad it's a duplicate :)

Comment: then whats that mean Comparable<? extends T>       ?

Comment: @user5533204 it means something that implemented the `Comparable` interface with a type that `extends` the generic `T` type

Comment: can u please elaborate? may be with practical example

Comment: I could, but not here since this question is already closed. Maybe look a little online and in Stack Overflow, and if you don't find an answer then open a new question and I'll answer there ;)

Comment: k no problem :) thnx anyways