# What is the difference between return type ResponseEntity<?> and ResponseEntity<Object> and ResponseEntity<MyCustomClass>

Tags: java, spring, controller

Right now I need my controller to return 2 different type of Object based on business logic, So my question is should I use

```
ResponseEntity <?>
```

or should I use:

```
ResponseEntity <Object>
```

What is the difference between this ***return types*** and why should I use them?

Does it make any changes to JSON returned by Spring controller?

I'm asking about ***return types, not input parameter.***

I use Spring MVC 4.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between ? and Object in Java generics?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/678822/what-is-the-difference-between-and-object-in-java-generics)

Answer (score 1):

Think about this problem as

```
ResponseEntity<?>
```

being equivalent to

```
ResponseEntity<? extends Object>
```

An instance of `SomeClass<String>` matches `SomeClass<?>` but not `SomeClass<Object>`.

I think it's common misunderstanding that in Java List is not a subtype of List, while String[] is in fact a subtype of Object[].
That's one of the reasons why generics and arrays don't mix well. Arrays in Java are covariant, generics are not, they are invariant.

So, to sum it up, you could use `ResponseEntity<?>` and use it in your controller like this

```
if (somecondition)
    return new ResponseEntity<Success>(HttpStatus.OK);
else
    return new ResponseEntity<Error>(HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
```